# Select Columns with prefix

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

A table I am using has 114 columns, but I only want to select columns that start with 'UDF_%'

Data:

| Dept Number | Employee Key | UDF_F_Name | UDF_L_Name | UDF_Hire Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 243 | 111111 | Employee 1 | Test | 3/18/2024 |
| 244 | 222222 | Employee 2 | Test | 3/1/2024 |

I have attempted a few things I found on the internet to not avail:

```
Select c.Column_Name
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns as C
where c.Table_Name = 'JT_Employee'
    and c.COLUMN_NAME like 'UDF_%'
```

This provided all of the column names that I want, but it provided as rows only. Now I am trying to use that query as a sub-query to provide the column names:

```
Select
    (
    Select c.Column_Name
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns as C
    where c.Table_Name = 'JT_Employee'
        and c.COLUMN_NAME like 'UDF_%'
    )
From JT_Employee
```

```
Select column_name, table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
Where table_name in ('JT_Employee')
and column_name = 'UDF_%'
```

The final results I am hoping to obtain are the columns that start with 'UDF_%' and remove all of the others:

| UDF_F_Name | UDF_L_Name | UDF_Hire Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | Test | 3/18/2024 |
| Employee 2 | Test | 3/1/2024 |

**I was able to get the following to provide me the string I need of my column names but am unable to get it to activate as column name select in a different query**

```
Select Distinct
    Stuff((Select c.Column_Name +', '
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns as C
    where c.Table_Name = 'JT_Employee'
        and c.COLUMN_NAME like 'UDF_%'
    FOR XML PATH ('')),1,0,'')
```

Comment: You can aggregate the names with help of STRING_AGG, something like: `Select STRING_AGG(c.Column_Name, ',')....` and then just use that string

Comment: Use the query to build the select statement. Then copy paste.

Comment: Does your table really have 114 properties? Smells like a design problem.

Comment: Hi @siggemannen, I tried this but was getting the response that String_AGG is not a built in function.

Comment: @TheImpaler, 114 columns over 500 rows with 114 columns worth of data.

Comment: What does `Select @@version` return

Comment: @siggemannen

I was able to get the query written to return the string of all of my column names to work, but I cannot get another string to accept those as the column names. I will add the new query above.

Comment: You can do something like this: `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = stuff((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Column_Name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns AS C
WHERE c.Table_Name = 'JT_Employee'
AND c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'UDF_%'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION FOR xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

EXEC ('select ' + @sql + ' from JT_Employee')`

Answer (score 0):

@Siggemannen was able to the answer:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT  @sql = stuff((

SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Column_Name)
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns AS C
WHERE   c.Table_Name = 'JT_Employee'
AND c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'UDF_%' 
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION 
FOR xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')  

EXEC    ('select ' + @sql + ' from JT_Employee') –
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Hi @JeremyCaney, I would love to but I am unable to tell you how it works 

Siggmannen was able to create it and it works but I can't fathom how, while I am still trying to understand it.